# Android: How to activate power button programmatically?

Tags: android, disconnect

I am trying to develop an app that disconnects an incoming call automatically.. I read somewhere that on pressing the power button, the call gets disconnected.. Could anyone let me know how to do this through the code? i.e i want to activate the intent for power button just like the below code that does it for the media button:

```
Intent buttonUp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
buttonUp.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
ctx.sendOrderedBroadcast(buttonUp, "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this but I believe you are looking for [KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_POWER). Try dispatching a [KeyEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html) with this code.

Comment: i have use both KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER and also dispatchKeyEvent method also but code inside this condition is not work ..
please help me out